# Calculating for time difference using nanoTime() but getting a negative number

Tags: java, nanotime

Here is my code in my main that calculates for the time difference of selectionSort() using nanoTime():

```
    System.out.println("Start time :: " + test.start());
    test.selectionSort();
    System.out.println("End time :: " + test.end());
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.print("Time took to run selectionSort() == ");
    System.out.println((test.getElapsedTime()) + " nanoseconds");
```

and my start(), end(), and getElapsedTime() methods are:

```
    public long start(){
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    return startTime;
    }

    public long end(){
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    return endTime;
    }

    public long getElapsedTime(){
    return end() - start();
    }
```

After running this program, the output is:

```
    5 2 9 7 4 3 0 1 6 8 
    Start time :: 915929737160723
    End time :: 915929737309925
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    Time took to run selectionSort() == -5921 nanoseconds
```

How come the getElapsedTime() method returns a negative number when it's supposed to be a positive?

Comment: I guess this is Java. You should edit the question and add a tag for the programming language. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, benchmarking is tricky, and especially unreliable with tasks that only take a few milliseconds, like sorting 10 elements. Have a look at the related answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElapsedTime` does not substract `startTime` from `endTime`, but resets them in the calls to `end()` and `start()`. Both calls happen nearly simultaneously, and return new nanotimes. `start()` apparently happens to be evaluated a bit later, so the result is a small negative number.

Proposed fix:

```
public long getElapsedTime() {
  return endTime - startTime;
}
```

Comment: Weird. I'm familiar with Java, only know c c++. How can you work with a language that reschedules commands for you in a way that they behave unpredictable? I mean, `end()` should IMHO never be called before `start()`

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius added the fix to my answer, maybe this helps? There is no black magic going on - the measured nanotimes just get overwritten in nearly the same moment.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't fully grasp the bigger picture. Even though they're called very close to each other, `start ()` should always be called before `end()`. And their output should refer to the system time, that should never decrease. How can the result ever be negative?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I am talking about the line `return end() - start();` - do you really expect `start()` to be evaluated before `end()`?

Comment: Hmm, good point... let me think about this. I'm probably saying something stupid....

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the time in a variable, like this:

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
doThings(); //This is what you want to measure
elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
System.out.println((elapsedTime + " nanoseconds");
```